# getWindow() method inside Services

Tags: android, service

I know Services has no UI but I want to use getWindow() inside services.I also know that I can use activity reference. But I want to use this service in different activities. is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: i am trying to send the image over socket.But the problem is that when I am changing my activity how I can use the same socket

Answer (score 1):

A Service runs on the same thread as your UI.  You can connect to your UI from a Service if you want to, but before you pursue that path, what are you trying to do? Do you want to use the same Service across apps?

Comment: Yes I want to use the same service throughout my apps.And please provide me some sample code also